# Is this sentence correctly phrased?

Tags: future-perfect

> He will have had the operation by may and should be a lot fitter then.

Have I phrased the sentence correctly? By this sentence, what I understand is -*He probably will do the operation- in future- by the time which is mentioned.*

In addition, what does the following mean?

> *....should be a lot fitter then.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence sound fine to me.

> ....should be a lot fitter then.

It means he should (*you are expecting him to*) be more fit than he is now.